# Does DB server pushes predicates to underline query of view if we are doing query on view with predicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, predicate, sql-view

I am using MySQL and I have a complex view which is causing performance issue.

Definition of view_3

`select * from view_1 union select * from view_2`

Now when I run a query to view_3 like below

`select * from view_3 where clolumn_a=value;`

This is processing a large set of rows may be doing full table scan and then returning a result.

So would it be better to do a query like below

`select * from view_1 where column_a=value union select * from view_2 where column_a=value;`

Does this behavior of view processing will remain the same in other SQL servers like Oracle, MSSQL

Does predicates will get pushed to underline query of view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a view is like a "Macro" from some other languages. The definition of the view is "expanded out" into the query that is using it, and then the entire query (now just composed of access to the real base tables, no views) is optimized as a whole.

Assuming the optimizer is doing it's job right, it should be able to push any predicates "down" - perhaps choosing to use an index seek rather than a table scan, if appropriate indices are available that match up with your predicates.

If you want to see exactly what the optimizer *has* done with your query, learn how to obtain and read the execution plans. In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), this would be done via [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan).